# How i can create a jquery script with var btn1 onclick change css

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi I want to create several buttons that change the css how i can do this
and click it again to undo it

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
```

```html
<button id="btn">bold</button>
<button id="btn2">italic</button>
<button id="btn3">underline</button>
<div class="item-1"></div>
```

Comment: you want to add this style to "<div class="item-1"></div>
" this div ?

Comment: yes i want this

Comment: Answer is added for this question regarding jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a proper way then you need to use jquery `toggleClass()` method like below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".item-1").toggleClass("red");
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
  $(".item-1").toggleClass("blue");
});

$("#btn3").click(function(){
  $(".item-1").toggleClass("green");
});
});
```

```css
.red
{
color:red;
}
.blue
{
color:blue;
}

.green
{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">red</button>
<button id="btn2">blue</button>
<button id="btn3">Green</button>
<br>
<div class="item-1">color</div>
```

Comment: @MichaelBurat i checked above snippet with this version 
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.slim.min.js   and its working as we expect

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes for toggle(do-undo) properties.

Css:

```
.boldText{
font-weight:Bold;
}
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
var txt = $('.item-1');
btn.onclick = function(){
txt.toggleClass('boldText')
}
```

```css
.boldText{
font-weight:Bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">bold</button>
<button id="btn2">italic</button>
<button id="btn3">underline</button>
<div class="item-1">test Text</div>
```

You can also add italic and underline options.

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami question title has 'jquery script'. Also question has 'jquery' tag.